# How to specify and estimate the parameters of a model that is quadratic in several variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model-selection, quadratic-form

I am trying to find how the quadratic model for a multiple featured dataset will be. Suppose that my training set is $X_1,...X_n$ with each $X$ of dimension $4$.

Now suppose I want to fit a quadratic function to this data. Then my model will be

$$h(X) = a_1 + a_2X + a_3X^2$$

where $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ are the parameters of my model to be estimated. Since the $X$s in the above equation are vectors that means that my parameters $a_2$ and $a_3$ also need to be vectors right? So how can I learn these parameters?

Comment: Since the $X$s are vectors, how are you defining $X^2$ exactly - element-wise or $X'X$, or...?

Comment: I am defining them element wise

Comment: Are you trying to estimate $a_1,a_2,a_3$ from data? If so, do you have observations of $h(X)$?

Comment: I don't have the exact data. I am just assuming them to know what I should do when I have such data

Comment: OK, so you'd like to know how to go about fitting this model if you did have observations of $h(X)$?

Comment: I just want to know what the dimension of the parameters a1,a2,a3 look like if I want to fit a quadratic model and the variables X are of dimension lets say 4. Let say I have the following observation (y,x) = {1, [ 3 5 8 9])} for example and so on the other observations. In this condition I believe a2 should be of dimension 4 as well. Then how can I learn this multidimensional parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your predictor ${\bf X} = \{ X_1, ..., X_p \}'$ is of dimension $p$ and ${\bf X}^2$ denotes the element-wise square of ${\bf X}$, then

$$ g({\bf X}) = a_1 + a_2 {\bf X} + a_3 {\bf X}^2 $$

will be a $p$-dimensional output if $a_2, a_3$ are scalars and will be a scalar output if $a_2, a_3$ are $p$-length vectors. Based on our comment discussion, you are interested in the latter so to answer your first question, yes, $a_2, a_3$ do need to be vectors.

To answer your second question,

*How can I learn about these parameters?*

Let $a_2 = \{a_{21}, ..., a_{2p} \}$ and $a_3 = \{a_{31}, ..., a_{3p} \}$. Then, doing the matrix multiplication, we can rewrite your model as

$$ g({\bf X}) = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{p} a_{2k} X_k + \sum_{k=1}^{p} a_{3k} X^{2}_k $$

Therefore, your model is just a quadratic regression model in your $p$ predictors with no interactions between predictors and $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the regression coefficients. The best linear unbiased estimator of the coefficients can be calculated using least squares, which minimizes

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( {\bf Y}_i - a_1 - \sum_{k=1}^{p} a_{2k} X_{ik} - \sum_{k=1}^{p} a_{3k} X^{2}_{ik} \right)^2 $$

as a function of $a_1, a_2, a_3$, where ${\bf Y}_i$ and ${\bf X}_i = \{ X_{i1} , ..., X_{ip} \}$ denote the $i$'th observation of the outcome and the predictor vector, respectively.

In your case $p=4$ and you can calculate this estimator in `R` using the `lm()` function. Specifically,

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x4^2))
```

where `y` are the observed values of ${\bf Y}$s, `x1,x2,x3,x4` denote the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th entries of ${\bf X}$, respectively.